# Convert Char in Int swift

Tags: swift, char, int, converters

I'm trying to convert a char in int, in C it works, but in Swift I've got some problem. It's not the same in C, using ascii I've got no problem.

This func is a piece of my atoi func.

I tried with binaryInt and UnicodeScalar, but didn't get success

```swift
func scanNumber(_ strArray: [Character], _ index: Int, _ flag: Int) -> Int {

    var resalt = 0

    while ((strArray[index] >= "0") && (strArray[index] <= "9")) {
        // flag mean plus or minus sign in strArray, if flag = 2 it's like a ["-", "1", "2", "3"]
        if flag != 2 {
            resalt *= 10
            resalt = resalt + Int(strArray[index]) //error
        } else {
            resalt *= 10
            resalt = resalt - Int(strArray[index]) //error
        }
    }
    return resalt
}
```

Int(strArray[index]) return:

> Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Character' conform to 'BinaryInteger'

Comment: You could use the [asciiValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127002-asciivalue) property: `Int(strArray[index].asciiValue ?? 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using asciiValue

```
func scanNumber(_ strArray: [Character], _ index: Int, _ flag: Int) -> Int {

    var resalt = 0
    var arrayIndex = index

    while (arrayIndex < strArray.count && (strArray[arrayIndex] >= "0") && (strArray[arrayIndex] <= "9")) {
        guard let ascii = strArray[arrayIndex].asciiValue  else {
           return resalt
        }
        resalt *= 10

        if flag != 2 {
            resalt += Int(ascii) - 48
        } else {
            resalt -= Int(ascii) - 48

        }
        arrayIndex += 1
    }
    return resalt
}
```

I also fixed the loop

Comment: ***Thanks!***  `Int(ascii) - 48` I like it :) Why we have to take this `arrayIndex < strArray.count` into account? I think that the loop will be interrupted as soon as the array is outside the bounds of 0 and 9.

Comment: @Buz-pro Not if the array contains _only_ numbers (or ends with numbers) then the check in the `while` will be out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

With a Character you can create a String. And with a String you can create an Int.

`let char: Character = "1"
if let number = Int(String(char)) {
    // use number

}`